# Is there a method to determine if a System.IO.StreamWriter object is open?

Tags: powershell, file-io, streamwriter

Im trying to determine if a `StreamWriter` object is open or already closed in a script.  If it's not closed, I can write a new line to the file.  If it is closed, I need to perform other actions....

How can I verify if a stream is still open?

Example test script.

```
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "C:\testing.txt"
$stream.WriteLine("TEST")
$stream.close()
if($stream)){
    #stream still open, write new line
    $stream.WriteLine("Stream is still open.  Write.")
    $stream.close()
}else(
    #stream not open... end script, send reponse.
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if a `BaseStream` exists for the `Streamwriter`-object. Like this:

```
if($stream.BaseStream)){
    #Stream is open
}
```

Example:

```
$sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter "C:\test.txt"

PS > $sw | fl *


AutoFlush      : False
BaseStream     : System.IO.FileStream
Encoding       : System.Text.UTF8Encoding
FormatProvider : nb-NO
NewLine        : 

PS > if($sw.BaseStream) { "yes" }
yes

PS > $sw.Close()

PS > if($sw.BaseStream) { "yes" }

PS > $sw


AutoFlush      : False
BaseStream     : 
Encoding       : 
FormatProvider : nb-NO
NewLine        :
```

**EDIT** Or you can check one of these:

```
if($sw.BaseStream.CanWrite) {
    #You have permission to write = stream open and writeable
    }

#or

if($sw.BaseStream.SafeFileHandle) {
    #you have a filehandle = stream open
    }
```

Comment: If you close the underlying stream directly, this won't work.  (I didn't notice that `stream` is actual a StreamWriter)